# Google Cloud Queue Tasks resolves with PERMISSION_DENIED(7): HTTP status code 403

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I'm using Google Cloud Queue tasks in my project where I'm able to create tasks that are added to my Queue in a scheduled time, but when the tasks are executed it throws: `Google PERMISSION_DENIED(7): HTTP status code 403.`
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKhU4.png)

I followed the guidance from Google Cloud Tasks documentation, but there is something missing with permissions. [Guide](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/samples/cloud-tasks-create-http-task-with-token#cloud_tasks_create_http_task_with_token-nodejs)

I'm using the createHttpTask function that they provide as example in the https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/tasks library.

```
const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer 'xxx'"
      },
      httpMethod: "POST",
      url,
      body: Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)).toString("base64"),
      oidcToken: {
        serviceAccountEmail,
        audience: url
      }
    }
  };
```

As you can see I added the serviceAccount and the audience in the task request

I created a new service account with this roles: [Service account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAfnD.png)

I also enable the Google Tasks API, and I have another service account with this permissions Default Google API Tasks service account: [Google Task API service account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be871.png)

Is there any other permissions that I'm missing? Or am I missing a step?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the service account that you use in the same project as the task queue?

Comment: Yes it is! @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere is there any other hint you can give us?

Comment: Do you have a service account in that form in the IAM page (activate the google manage service account list) `service-<ProjectNUMBER>@gcp-sa-cloudtasks.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. If so, what is the roles of it?

Comment: Another question, are you trying to reach a Cloud Functions gen2 or gen1 with your task?

Comment: got it to run? facing the same issue?